# Где/Как лучше изучать работу с DOM?

Tags: javascript

Я практически новичек. На практике в основном использую jQuery для того что бы "считывать" какие либо события ( к примеру : клик, наведение и прочее) и хочу все больше избавляться от нужды использования этой библиотеки , хотя она безусловно очень удобная. Я хотел бы узнать , где можно в полной мере все это рассмотреть/изучить, какой(ие) ресурс(ы) использовать, будь то книга или ещё что.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript и https://learn.javascript.ru/ больше ничего не нужно. Если что-то не получается, всегда можно тут уточнить. Конечно, после того, как будет показан код, с которым возникли проблемы.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ - 2часть про DOM, доступно и понятно, но лучше изучать на конкретном проекте